# talking to a network device on windows and on linux

Tags: linux, windows, networking

I have an antenna dish pedestal. Something that looks like this (just one of these). Eventually pedestal will have an dish antenna connected to it.

[image]

This pedestal has two motors to rotate the dish horizontally and vertically. Each motor has an IP address. For the sake of the discussion let's assume they are 10.10.10.161 and 10.10.10.162

The company (can't disclose it) that makes the pedestals provides a Windows application to communicate with the pedestal over Ethernet (sends UDP packets).

We tried pinging both of the motors from Windows and had no issues. However when we ping the motors from Linux there is no response.

We tried looking up online what could be the issue but didn't find any reasonable answers. To add to our problems, our project manager doesn't allow us to contact the pedestal manufacturer. We must find an explanation of the problem first and then we can let the manufacturer know what the issue is.

Has anyone encountered this type of problem before (able to ping from Windows but not able to ping from Linux)? If yes, then wow did you resolve the issue? What are we missing?

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) or [unix.se] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Are the Linux systems on the same subnet as the pedestals?

Comment: If you say pinging, you actually mean using the "ping" utility of both OSes to send an icmp packet to the thing?

Comment: What does this have to do with UDP? Ping doesn't use UDP.

Comment: If they're on the same subnet, does the address show up in the ARP cache of the Linux machine?

Comment: @Barmar Linux and pedestals are on the same subnet. We know that ping doesn't use UDP. Simply included it to give a full picture of the software developed by the manufacturer

Comment: @fvu yes, actual ping utility of both OSes

Comment: But you put it into the title, suggesting that it's what this question is about.

Comment: @Barmar I see. I can remove if it is necessary.

Comment: too late, I already did that

Comment: Have you tried sniffing the traffic from the Windows and Linux machines to find the differences in what they're sending/find the protocol for communicating with the motors?

Comment: 1 - the only obvious difference I know is that Windows uses 32 byte packets whereas Linux by default uses 64 bytes and 2 - do you know what OS that pedestal is running? nmap can help you to figure that out.

Comment: @fvu I don't know what OS the pedestal is running. I've never used nmap before. Are there any specific commands I need to run to figure our the OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an illustration of the difference between the Windows vs. Linux `ping` command.

Notes:

- Linux system = 192.168.1.201
- Windows system = 192.168.1.7
- the outputs below are from `tcpdump` packet captures

When pinging from Windows:

```
18:21:38.740379 IP 192.168.1.7 > 192.168.1.201: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 3094, length 40
18:21:38.740433 IP 192.168.1.201 > 192.168.1.7: ICMP echo reply, id 1, seq 3094, length 40
```

When pinging from Linux:

```
18:29:44.152333 IP 192.168.1.201 > 192.168.1.7: ICMP echo request, id 11524, seq 1, length 64
18:29:44.152460 IP 192.168.1.7 > 192.168.1.201: ICMP echo reply, id 11524, seq 1, length 64
```

The `id` and `seq` are inconsequential. However, `length` is a material difference.

To make Linux match Windows on that front, you can specify a packet size (which sets the size of the data payload, which will have 8 bytes of overhead added on top).

This Linux command:

```
$ ping 192.168.1.7 -s 32
```

Results in this packet capture:

```
18:30:59.528357 IP 192.168.1.201 > 192.168.1.7: ICMP echo request, id 11569, seq 2, length 40
18:30:59.528522 IP 192.168.1.7 > 192.168.1.201: ICMP echo reply, id 11569, seq 2, length 40
```

---

Regarding the use of `nmap`, you can use the `-O` flag to enable it's [operating system detection feature](https://nmap.org/book/man-os-detection.html).

```
$ nmap -O <target IP>
```